# Facebook friends retrieved with koala are less than Facebook the number Facebook shows

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala-gem

I have 616 Facebook friends and Koala gem returns only 601.

Here is the code I use:

```
if user.facebook_identities.present?
  token = user.facebook_identities.first.token
  secret = GetFacebookEntry.new.execute[1]
  graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(token, secret)
  friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends", fields: "first_name, last_name, id")

  friends.map do |x|
    x.merge provider: :facebook,
            avatar_url: GetFacebookImageService.new(x['id']).execute,
            user_id: x['id']
  end
end
```

Any idea what could happen? Why those 10 friends are lost?

Comment: Maybe the results are being paged? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1 (The section is called Traversing Paged Results)